# Merging two dataframes and conditionally calculating new colum with custom function - Unconverted data remains: t

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to create a column in a dataFrame that would be the result of two other

In the example below, two dataFrames were created: df1 and df2.

Then a third dataFrame was created, which is the junction of the first two. In this df3, the "Dates" column has been changed to the dateTime type.

After that, the column "DateMonth" was created, whose month was extracted from the "Dates" column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from datetime import datetime

# df1 and df2:
id_sales   = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
col_names  = ['Id', 'parrotId', 'Dates']
df1        = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
df1.Id     = id_sales
df1.parrotId = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
df1.Dates  = ['1900-01-01', '2012-08-20', '1900-01-01', '1900-01-01', '2016-02-21', '2012-08-21']

col_names2 = ['parrotId', 'months']
df2        = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names2)
df2.parrotId = [1, 2, 3]
df2.months = [('Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec'), ('Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec'), ('Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec')]

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'parrotId')
df3.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df3['Dates'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

With the help of Lukas user, the following function was created

```
def matched(row):
    if type(row['months'])==str:
        # for the case ('Feb, Mar, Apr') - get numerical representation of month from your string and return True if the 'Dates' value matches with some list item
        return row['Dates'].month in [datetime.strptime(mon.strip()[:3], '%b').month for mon in row['months'].split(',')]  
    else:
        # for numbers - return True if months match
        return row['Dates'].month==row['months']
```

Applying:

```
df3['DateMonth'] = df3.apply(matched, axis=1).astype(int)
```

In the example above, I had no problems. But when replicating in my dataset I received the following error message:

> ValueError: ('unconverted data remains: t', 'occurred at index 16772')

Column Dates is type
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Index 16772:

```
months     Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec
Dates      2015-07-31 00:00:00
```

Index 16771:

```
months     Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
Dates      2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

The unique values are:

```
array([0, 'Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct', 'Feb,May,Aug,Nov', 'Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec'],
      dtype=object)
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Is there by chance a "Sept" in your data somewhere where there should be a "Sep"?

Comment: Please give me an example on how to check this in the DataFrame

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to deal with dataframes, but the only way that error makes sense is if you tried that `datetime.strptime()` call on a string that consists of a valid three-letter month name plus an additional "t". (Edit: The error also mentions index 16772. That might help you find it.)

Comment: What does the data look like at index 16772?  Your MCVE runs on my side fine.

Comment: @glibdud points out the error.  Place `df2.months = [12, ('Febt, Mar, Mar'), 0]` in your MCVE.

Comment: Reading the comments and the answer, it seems that the problem is the fact that in some lines there is a month with 4 characters.

I have edited the question in order to present what is informed in the index 16772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data is incorrect.

Make sure `datetime.strptime()` gets good input data.  For example, `strptime` `%b` needs a three letter month.

In `match()` strip the space from the split and slice the result to three characters.

```
        return row['Dates'].month in [datetime.strptime(mon.strip()[:3], '%b').month for mon in row['months'].split(',')]
```

Working example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from datetime import datetime

# df1 and df2:
id_sales   = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
col_names  = ['Id', 'parrotId', 'Dates']
df1        = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
df1.Id     = id_sales
df1.parrotId = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
df1.Dates  = ['2012-12-25', '2012-08-20', '2013-07-23', '2014-01-14', '2016-02-21', '2015-10-31']

col_names2 = ['parrotId', 'months']
df2        = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names2)
df2.parrotId = [1, 2, 3]
df2.months = [12, ('Febt,Mar,Mar'), 0]

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'parrotId')
df3.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df3['Dates'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
# determine if df3['Dates'].month is zero or one offset (is one)
#print(df3['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.month))

#exit(0)

def matched(row):
    #print("Will process row", row)
    if type(row['months'])==str:
        # for the case ('Feb, Mar, Apr') - get numerical representation of month from your string and return True if the 'Dates' value matches with some list item
        print (row['Dates'].month)
        # determine if datetime.strptime is zero or one offset (is one)
        # print ([datetime.strptime(mon.strip()[:3], '%b').month for mon in row['months'].split(',')])
        return row['Dates'].month in [datetime.strptime(mon.strip()[:3], '%b').month for mon in row['months'].split(',')]        
    else:
        # for numbers - return True if months match
        return row['Dates'].month==row['months']

df3['DateMonth'] = df3.apply(matched, axis=1).astype(int)

datetime.strptime('Mar'[:4], '%b').month

print (df3)
```

Comment: I changed the function with the suggested code. No error returned, but results were inconsistent. For the same values, different results were attributed. For example, date 1900-01-01 and months Mar, Jun, Sept, Dec; sometimes returned 0 and sometimes returned 1.

Comment: Update your code in your Q so other folks can focus on the now semantic error.

Comment: Okay. I already did this and it exemplifies with the index that presented error and with one that did not present an error. However, the results are now inconsistent. I really do not understand why.

Comment: I see `mon.strip(), '%b'` and not `mon.strip()[:3], '%b'` in your example above.  On my side, it appears to work but don't have all of the input data.

Comment: If you've got it working, please accept the answer.  If not, maybe you can shed some light on what the inconsistency is.

Comment: I have re-modeled the example now. Unfortunately, the example works perfectly. In practice, for the same input data the (corrected) function returns different values ​​(True and False).

Comment: I think I'm very tired. I have two columns relative to the date in the dataFrame. I was comparing the wrong dates. Your answer is correct. I apologize to everyone for wasting time.

Comment: Not a waste of time.  Consider updating your question title to reflect the question and answer for future learners. "Merging two dataframes and conditionally calculating new colum with custom function" or something.  Good luck!